# How to run awk on Windows 11

Tags: windows, awk

I have run gawk on Windows 7, using the "cmd"-window. However, on Windows 11, the "cmd"-window is no longer available.

Is it possible to run an awk (gawk) program on Windows 11? What needs to be prepared and/or installed on Windows 11 to achieve this?

On Windows 7, I would typically write this type of command in the "cmd"-window:
gawk-w32.exe program.txt inputdata.txt > outputdata.txt

I hope to be able to execute a similar functionality on Windows 11, maybe through an "awk app", if such a thing exsists.

I have not been able to find any hints on how to solve my problem through searches on relevant words (awk windows 11), using the Bing search engine.

Comment: is powershell available in Windows 11? the `gawk-w32.exe` it not a standard component of  Windows 7 which means you must've run some sort of add-on/3rd-party installation package to get `gawk-w32.exe` installed in Windows 7 ... so I'm wondering if you'll have to do that for Windows 11, too?  another option might be to look into 'Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)' which consists (I think) of getting a linux VM (eg, Ubuntu) running under Windows (I don't have Windows 11, nor have I used WSL ... I'm just passing along what I've seen crop up in other questions)

Comment: *the "cmd"-window is no longer available.* - of course no.

Comment: Microsoft has **finally** caught up with the modern times on this. `cmd` on Win10 still looks almost like on dos 6.11, some 30 years back. Now [Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-terminal-is-now-the-default-in-windows-11/) is default. And it's much better. You can of course run awk in terminal.

Comment: Thank you! The tip about using "Windows Terminal" was exactly what I needed! It seems to solve my problem completely.

Answer (score 0):

If your `inputdata.txt` is not very big and is not considered ULTRA secrecy you might consider using [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/l/awk-gawk) which is *Online AWK (gawk) compiler and IDE*. Keep in mind that you are limited to working with *standard input* and you would need to copy paste your data each time.